# How to send my jQuery form to node.js connect-form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Server side, I use below function (used as espressjs middleware)

```
function objCreation(req, res, next){
  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files){
    if (err) {
       next(err);
    } else {
       // Set params in request
       obj = {};
       obj.label = fields.label;
       // Check if picture is provided
       if(files.image){
          // Move file to correct dir
          var fs = require("fs");
          var folder = '/var/images/';
          var src = files.image.path;
          var filename = files.image.name;
          var target = folder + filename;

          obj.filename = filename;
          req.obj = obj;

           fs.rename(src, target, function (status) {
             next();
          });
       } else {
          obj.filename = 'nofile';
          req.obj = obj;
          next();
       }
    }
  });
}
```

Basically, it receives the fields of a form submitted. This function uses "connect-form" node.js module.

Client side, I use an input text:

```
<input id="new_obj" type="text" placeholder="New"/>
```

and a callback triggered when return is hit on this input:

```
// Add callback for object creation
$('#new_obj').keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which == 13){
    createObj();
  }
});
```

The createObj function is the following one:

```
function createObj(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "/object/create/",
   type: "POST",
   data: { label : "label" },
   success: function(obj) {
     console.log(obj);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR,status,errorThrown) {
     alert(jqXHR.responseText + '-' + status + '-' + errorThrown);
   }
 });
}
```

I do not manage to have this last part sending a form in the correct format so it is processed with the server method. I do not want to change the server side as it is already used by some other clients (iOS client sending form with ASIFormDataRequest).

I'm currently having a look at ajaxForm jQuery plugin to see if this could help.

Comment: You need to use multipart

 <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have this fixed by using the last version of expressjs that does not use connect-form anymore (deprecated) but uses formidable instead.